# Java Spring - How to use classpath to specify a file location?

Tags: java, spring, classpath

How can I use the classpath to specify the location of a file that is within my Spring project?

This is what I have currently:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Corey\\Desktop\\storedProcedures.sql");
```

This is hardcoded to my Desktop. What I would like is to be able to use the path to the file that is in my project.

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("/src/main/resources/storedProcedures.sql");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Are we talking about standard [`java.io.FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)? Won't work, but it's not hard without it.

`/src/main/resources` maven directory contents are placed in the root of your CLASSPATH, so you can simply retrieve it using:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/storedProcedures.sql");
```

If the result is not `null` (resource not found), feel free to wrap it in a reader:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

Comment: This really worked for me in Spring but how do I do this with _WRITING_? I have tried various `BufferedWriter` implementations but none worked T_T

Comment: My problem exactly! I somehow got to read the file but will someone enlighten me on What to use in case of WRITING?

Answer (score 12):

From an answer of @NimChimpsky in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22097153/491245):

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("storedProcedures.sql");
InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

Using [ClassPathResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) and interface [Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html). And make sure you are adding the resources directory correctly (adding `/src/main/resources/` into the classpath).

Note that Resource have a method to get a `java.io.File` so you can also use:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("storedProcedures.sql");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(resource.getFile());
```

Answer (score 5):

Spring has org.springframework.core.io.Resource which is designed for such situations. From context.xml you can pass classpath to the bean

```
<bean class="test.Test1">
        <property name="path" value="classpath:/test/test1.xml" />
    </bean>
```

and you get it in your bean as Resource:

```
public void setPath(Resource path) throws IOException {
    File file = path.getFile();
    System.out.println(file);
    }
```

output

```
D:\workspace1\spring\target\test-classes\test\test1.xml
```

Now you can use it in new FileReader(file)

Comment: You can replace Resource in the setter to File to save you having to call path.getFile();

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have maven project and so resources are in classpath by

go for

```
getClass().getResource("classpath:storedProcedures.sql")
```

Comment: `classpath:` prefix does not work in core Java, it's Spring-specific.

Comment: sure, question is about `spring`