# Spring MVC : read file from src/main/resources

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a maven Spring project, there is `xml` file inside `src/main/resources/xyz.xml`. How can I read it inside spring MVC controller.

I am using

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("classpath:xyz.xml");
```

but `is` is `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Spring - How to use classpath to specify a file location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571960/java-spring-how-to-use-classpath-to-specify-a-file-location)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(fileLocationInClasspath);
InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

using [ClassPathResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) and interface [resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html). But make sure you are copying the resources directory correctly (using maven), and its not missing, for example if running tests as part of test context.

Comment: In this case, fileLocationInClasspath should not start with "classpath:".

Comment: does this work if I need to read a folder from src/main/resources

Answer (score 28):

For spring based application you can take advantage of **ResourceUtils** class.

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:xyz.xml")
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html

Comment: Read file from resources folder – Spring Example https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/read-file-from-resources-folder/

Comment: The documentation states that it's "Mainly for internal use within the framework."

Answer (score 14):

Here is one way of loading classpath resources.

```
Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource("classpath:xyz.xml");
InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Hey Robby, this is super helpful but Kenji and I are wondering how you would then parse a file line by line from the input stream.

Answer (score 12):

You can add a field with annotation `@Value` to your bean:

```
@Value("classpath:xyz.xml")
private Resource resource;
```

And then simply:

```
resource.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Best working code in Dec 14, 2019 (Spring version 5.1.0.RELEASE)

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("xyz.xml");
InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();
File file = resource.getFile();
```

See [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-read-file-from-resources-folder/) for more details

Comment: Using ClassPathResource is exactly what I was looking for since it eliminates the need to write `classpath:` in the file path. Thanks for sharing this.