# Spring java -.properties file cannot be found

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties-file, applicationcontext

I try to update data in the "ex.properties" file. The current data is used by applicationContext.xml file. I tried every solution i found on internet but i still cannot determine the path of "ex.properties" file, when "CurrencyAddJob.java" tries to reach and alter the data.

Related part of "ex.properties" file applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dailyCountJobCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="dailyCountJob"/>
    <property name="group" value="DailyJobsTriggers"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${sched1}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="schedProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:ex.properties" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="environment">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

"ex.properties" file:

```
sched1=0/4 * * * * ?
```

location of "ex.properties": src/main/resources/ex.properties

CurrencyAddJob.java:
solution 1:

```
    try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("ex.properties");
            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.load(in);
            in.close();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ex.properties");

            props.setProperty("sched1", "0/1 * * * * ?");
            props.store(out, null);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

There is an exception is caught:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: ex.properties (The system cannot find
>   the file specified)

CurrencyAddJob.java:
solution 2:

```
    try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\Users\Honorius\Desktop\workspace\honoriusProject\src\main\resources\ex.properties");
            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.load(in);
            in.close();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\Users\Honorius\Desktop\workspace\honoriusProject\src\main\resources\ex.properties");

            props.setProperty("sched1", "0/1 * * * * ?");
            props.store(out, null);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

There is an exception is caught:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: ex.properties (The system cannot find
>   the file specified)

CurrencyAddJob.java:
solution 3:

```
    try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("ex.properties").getAbsolutePath());
            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.load(in);
            in.close();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("ex.properties").getAbsolutePath());

            props.setProperty("sched1", "0/1 * * * * ?");
            props.store(out, null);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

There is an exception is caught:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: ex.properties (The system cannot find
>   the file specified)

I also changed the directory of "ex.properties" but i couldn't get rid of the exception

Is there any alternative solution?
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22097153/3037869

Comment: Backslash in string constants needs to be escaped. Write `"C:\\Users\\Honorius\\Desktop\\workspace\\..."` instead of `"C:\Users\Honorius\..."`.

Comment: @Jesper ,you are right. I wrote like double backslash. While post here, i wrote single backslash. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ex.properties"));
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.load(in);
        in.close();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/ex.properties").getFile()));

        props.setProperty("sched1", "0/1 * * * * ?");
        props.store(out, null);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```