# Load json file from resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have problem with loading json file from resource.
Here is my code:

```
public void setConfiguration() {
        try {
            ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader(); 
            ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
            Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:/configuration.json");
            if (resources.length == 0) {
                log.warn("Configuration could not be loaded from file! Using default configuration.");
                configuration = getDefaultConfiguration();
            }
            for (Resource resource: resources){
                configuration = new ObjectMapper().readValue(resource.getInputStream(), Configuration.class);
                if (configuration != null) {
                    log.debug("Configuration found (using PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver)");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Configuration could not be loaded from file! Using default configuration.", e);
            configuration = getDefaultConfiguration();
        }
    }
```

It always take default configuration. Does anyone know why it doesn't take values from json file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC : read file from src/main/resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096983/spring-mvc-read-file-from-src-main-resources)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:
 `("classpath:"+this.config.getClassPathRoot() + "/**/*"+jsonFileExtension)`
for getting resources.

I this also not working try using the object by calling the default constructor as:
`PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pathResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();`

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:configuration.json");
        InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
        if (resourceInputStream == null) {
            log.warn("Configuration could not be loaded from file! Using default configuration.");
            configuration = getDefaultConfiguration();
        }
        else {
            configuration = new ObjectMapper().readValue(resourceInputStream, Configuration.class);
            if (configuration != null) {
                log.debug("Configuration found (using PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver)");
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Configuration could not be loaded from file! Using default configuration.", e);
        configuration = getDefaultConfiguration();
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I've got this exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name at this line: InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream(); My previous code work on local environment, but when i deploy to server it couldn't find this json file in config folder

Answer (score 0):

if your project is maven project, maybe you should add some configuration in your pom.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.json</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```