# Spring RestController: Return JSON resource

Tags: java, json, spring, resources

How can I server JSON on localhost with Spring? I want to serve a JSONFile from the project's resource directory through a RestController.

So far I have:

```
@RestController
public class JSONRestController {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listUsers(){
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("fileName").getFile());
        //or with an external library: org.springframework.util.StreamUtils
        String msg = StreamUtils.copyToString( new ClassPathResource("list.json").getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset()  );

        return file.toString() //not an existing method
    }
}
```

The purpose is to have a Spring application that can serve a JSON file from the resources through a REST endpoint. I want to get the file from the resources directory and return it as a JSON from a ResController endpoint. Then I want to be able to access it with a GET request originating from another application which is also on localhost.

Comment: Or return the resource directly (while setting the appropriate content type).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC : read file from src/main/resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096983/spring-mvc-read-file-from-src-main-resources)

Answer (score 0):

Define a RestController that fetches the JSON from the resources directory and returns it through a REST endpoint.
Here the JSON in resources is called `items.json` and the endpoint will be `localhost:8080/db` (assuming you did not change the server.port property).

```
@RestController
public class JSONController {

private JSONObject jsonObject;

    @GetMapping("/db")
    @CrossOrigin
    public JSONObject getJSON(){

        try {
            Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/items.json");
            InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(
                    new InputStreamReader(resourceInputStream, "UTF-8"));

        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```