# Spring MVC cannot access a text from resources in Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have created text file in resources in Spring MVC project and trying to access it in a controller to read the content. but it is giving me Not found exception.

```
    //ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        //File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("path.txt").getFile());

        String fp=new File("").getAbsolutePath(); //Absolute path returns the ecplise location and not the project or workspace location
    //  File f=ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:path.txt");
    //  File f = new File(getClass().getResource("path.txt").getFile());
    //  File f = new ClassPathResource("path.txt").getFile();
        // InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
    //  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fp+File.separator+"/path.txt"));
```

Comment: What is the relative file path of your file within your project? Make sure that it is stored inside your war/jar after build

Comment: I am able to access the file like this http://localhost:8080/spring_json/resources/path.txt

Answer (score 0):

From an answer of @NimChimpsky in [similar question:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22097153/491245)

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("path.txt");
InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

Using [ClassPathResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) and interface [Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html). And make sure you are adding the resources directory correctly (adding `/src/main/resources/` into the classpath).

Note that Resource have a method to get a `java.io.File` so you can also use:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("path.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(resource.getFile());
```

Comment: still the same thing, it doesn't work in Spring MVC works in servlet though