# FileNotFoundException in Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, derby

I am not able to resolve the issue am getting.

Full stacktrace:

```
12:14:08.172 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding    [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
12:14:08.178 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
12:14:08.178 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
12:14:08.183 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@24273305: startup date [Thu Mar 16 12:14:08 GMT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
12:14:08.222 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
12:14:08.223 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
12:14:08.223 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
12:14:08.233 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at org.postprocessor.dao.DaoMain.main(DaoMain.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
... 13 more
```

Bean config file `dataSupport.xml` is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- <bean/> definitions here -->
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.postprocessor.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.postprocessor.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.postprocessor.util" />



<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" 
        /> <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:postprocessor;create=true;" />
<!--    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db;create=true;" /> -->
    <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="daoImpl" class="org.postprocessor.dao.DaoImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>resourceBundles/general</value>
            <value>resourceBundles/codeLists/codelist_eortcqlqc30</value>
            <value>resourceBundles/codeLists/codelist_eortcqlqlc13</value>
            <value>resourceBundles/codeLists/codelist_eq5d3l</value>
            <value>resourceBundles/codeLists/codelist_eq5d5l</value>
            <value>resourceBundles/codeLists/codelist_noncompletedquestionnaires</value>
            <value>resourceBundles/codeLists/codelist_pgis</value>
            <value>resourceBundles/codeLists/codelist_silc</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

snipped from `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SBP</groupId>
<artifactId>SBP</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>gt20047</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-asm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derbynet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbynet</artifactId>
        <version>10.12.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derbyclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.12.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-pool/commons-pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<finalName>gt20047</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>

              <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                    <mainClass>org.postprocessor.dao.DaoMain</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

am not able to figure out where is the issue, my jar file doesn't have this config folder[image]

**DaoMain.java**

```
package org.postprocessor.dao;

import java.io.File;

import org.postprocessor.util.FileZipper;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DaoMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml");
        DaoImpl daoImpl=null;
        FileZipper fileZipper=null;
        try{
            daoImpl= ctx.getBean("daoImpl",DaoImpl.class);
            fileZipper= ctx.getBean("fileZipper",FileZipper.class);
            daoImpl.startProcess();
            fileZipper.zipFile(new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"/output");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) ctx).close();
        }
      }
    }
```

- **How to solve this issue?**

Comment: Post stacktraces as text not as image

Comment: where is `dataSupport.xml` located in your jar?

Comment: the build is not including this dataSupport.xml file, that's y I have the error

Comment: And where it is located? From where you want to read it?

Comment: it's under src/org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml here is the file located

Answer (score 12):

Looks like the main problem is at this line:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml");
```

You are trying to build context from `classpath`. Thus you have to locate your config file accessible from a classpath of your project.

You using **Maven** for building your project. Maven has defined project structure for ***code sources***:

```
/src/main/java
```

and for ***resources***:

```
/src/main/resorces
```

You can find more here: [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

If you want to make your file accessible from classpath you ***have to put it exactly under*** - `resources/` folder:

[image]

Now you ***main()*** will be, something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:config/dataSupport.xml");
    Object dataSource = ctx.getBean("userRepo");
    System.out.println(dataSource.getClass().getName());
    // use your beans here
```

I created just demo bean. And here is output:

```
2017-03-20 15:22:40 INFO  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@16f65612: startup date [Mon Mar 20 15:22:40 EET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-20 15:22:40 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [config/dataSupport.xml]
demo.repository.UserRepository
```

**BTW** you can use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for application context:

```
try(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx =
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:config/dataSupport.xml")) {
    // use your beans here
}
```

***Additional resources***:

- [using classpath: in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092713/using-classpath-in-spring)
- [Java Spring - How to use classpath to specify a file location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571960/java-spring-how-to-use-classpath-to-specify-a-file-location)

Answer (score 0):

Your XML files are not well formed.

While I do not know if this is the issue, it may be the root cause of why your project is not taking the files correctly in the first place.

Your `<beans>` tag does not have a closing tag. Try putting `</beans>` at the end of the file.

Also, your `pom.xml` file has the same issue. The `<project>` is not closed. Try putting `</project>` at the end of the file.

Comment: both files are correct but missed pasting here, apologies for the silly mistake... tried the issue is am not able to build jar file with this beans file, and hence am getting the error...but I can run the application using Java application in eclipse but I need the jar file to add it in the batch file...to run it

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work:

`ApplicationContext ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml");`

You don't need to specify "classpath" since you already use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, and you have extra slash in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

move:

`src/org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml`

to:

`src/main/resources/org/postprocessor/config/dataSupport.xml`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15641594)

Comment: OP asked: "How to solve this issue?" to which the answer is: "move your config file into the correct location". Is there something not clear about this?

Comment: You can improve the quality of your post by adding some explanation. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Hard to say whether someone couldn't figure out that moving the file into correct (expected) location means that the file wasn't where it was supposed to be? Hopefully people will read the accepted answer and figure out what is going on anyway.

Answer (score 0):

By default maven-compiler-plugin not includes non-java files. which left you with two options.
1. move your resource files (.properties, .xml etc) to "src/main/resources" (**recomended**.)
2. use maven resource plugin

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/path/where/you/want</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```